# ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template application/set_locale)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am currently setting the `locale` in my `ApplicationController` via passing the `locale` param via AJAX to the the following function in ApplicationController:

```
def set_locale
 I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
 Rails.logger.debug(I18n.locale)
 Rails.logger.debug(params)
end
```

How can I simply `:render` the necessary text for all the

`=t`

commands without out rendering a separate view but keeping the same DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your question title is being caused by an improper use of the `set_locale` method in your `ApplicationController`. You're treating it as an action, in other words, you're making a request to it, whether via AJAX or regular GET request. When the request hits this action it will try to render a view of the same name. It's apparent you don't have a `set_locale.html.erb` view in your views directory. To fix this issue simply `render nothing: true` at the bottom of the `set_locale` method.

But, what are you really trying to accomplish with this? It seems you're setting the `locale` by firing AJAX call after the page has loaded. I understand this could be from a user choosing a locale from a dropdown or something and you don't want to reload the page. But, reloading the page would be the simplest thing to do. Since you mentioned you have `= t` every where in your views, you really do have to have the controller re-render those views.

If you absolutely have to keep the same DOM, you'll have to code your own solution using JSON. Have the `set_locale` action render a JSON object such as:

```
{
  "#text_element1": I18n.t('the.text'),
  "#some-other-element": I18n.t('some.other.text')
}
```

And then have your ajax success callback find the elements given by the keys and insert the text given by the values of the JSON into them.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following system:
In my **nav menu**

```
<%= form_tag local_switcher_home_index_path, :class => 'locale' do %>
<%= select_tag 'locale_set', options_for_select(LANGUAGES, I18n.locale.to_s), :onchange => 'this.form.submit()' %>
<% end %>
```

In **LANGUAGES** contains the supporting languages.

```
LANGUAGES = [
   ['English' ,'en' ],
   ['Deutsch' , 'de']
]
```

In my **home_controller.rb**

```
def local_switcher
  if params[:locale_set]
    I18n.locale = params[:locale_set].to_sym
    set_session_and_redirect
  end
end

def set_session_and_redirect
   session[:locale] = I18n.locale
   redirect_to :back
  rescue ActionController::RedirectBackError
   redirect_to :root
end
```

Suppose, I'm currently on my **home/index.html.erb** page,

for printing a text i'll use:

```
<%= t('home.index.value') %>
```

in my language files:

```
en:
  home:
    index:
      value: "Yo!"

de:
  home:
    index:
      value: "Do!"
```

Hope it will help!